# Default selected not working angular js

Tags: angularjs

Trying to make my dropdown have a defaulted select but no matter what it doesn't appear to work. The code always generates the below:

Output:

```
<select ng-init="selectedFrom = phoneNumbers[0]" ng-options="phone.Number for phone in phoneNumbers" ng-model="selectedFrom" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <option value="?"></option>
    <option value="0">888-555-5551</option>
    <option value="1">888-555-5552</option>
</select>
```

I don't want it to create a blank select option and I want it o select the first option by default.

My Angular code looks like so:

```
<select ng-init="selectedFrom = phoneNumbers[0]" 
    ng-options="phone.Number for phone in phoneNumbers" 
    ng-model="selectedFrom">
</select>
```

Also no errors are being thrown in the console. So its not like something else is messing it up.

Comment: First I would strongly suggest copying and pasting the actual source code, any existing phone numbers should be stripped. Also you should be able to set it in your controller after receiving the data. `$scope.selectedFrom = $scope.phoneNumbers[0].Number;`

Comment: You should do the selection of the option inside your controller. Ng-init should only be used in very specific cases and this is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 separate options as I see it...

change your init to be:

```
selectedFrom = phoneNumbers[0]
```

or to change your ng-options to be:'

```
phone.Number for phone in phoneNumbers track by phone.Number
```

Here is an example **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8GzXg/)**

Comment: I tried both above still the same problem. I removed ng-init and the track by didn't work. I then removed the track by part and replace the ng-init with what you have still didnt work. I keep getting that blank option